# searching for old files cmd

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, wmi

I need to find all files with

1. certain extension
2. with date of last use higher than certain threshold (e.g. > 30
   days)

The problems are:

1. I don't know where file(s) could be (it means search through all
   local disks) - if this files are even exist
2. I don't know which OS it would be - definitely version of
   Windows, but it could be anything between XP and 2008
3. It has to be done on many computers.
4. The result supposed to be exit code of zero if no such file(s)
   are present, and non-zero if they are detected (plus txt report with
   path and time of last modifying)

So far I've find out how to find all files (*.NNN)-

```
for %%i in (c d e f g h i g k l m n q r s t u v w x y z) do dir /s /a-d %%i:\*.NNN
```

or how to find files in certain place with certain time stamp (> 30 days)

```
forfiles /p N:\NNNN /m *.NNN /d -30
```

Any thoughts around are more than welcome, thank you all in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "date of last use"? There is a "last accessed date", but it is unreliable because it is unreliable (the file can be accessed without updating the date). There is also a "last modified date" which is reliable. Perhaps you should explain why you want to do this - someone may have a better idea.

Comment: The reason is simple: clean up after an irresponsible users in wintel service provider environment. But first I have to ask them, do they REALLY need those huge old files (e.g. *.vhd, *.vmdk etc...)

Answer (score 1):

The following batch command queries the CIM_LogicalFile class for all system fileswith extension 'exe' where the files last modified date is greater than 31/07/2012 and outputs results to a CSV file:

```
wmic /namespace:\\root\cimv2 path CIM_LogicalFile where "Extension='exe' and LastModified>'20120731235959.000000+600'" get /all /format:csv >"CIM_LogicalFile.csv"
```

Comment: Thank you! I had some thoughts to use WMI, but didn't know how to start.

Comment: Welcome and good luck with WMI, it's the way to go if you want quick answers from your system. Checkout the following WMI references that may assist you further: <br>
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394531(v=vs.85).aspx <br>